# how to trace a site's javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I know this seems like a simple answer that I can google but I have been trying and can't figure it out. I have firebug and mozilla developer and chrome installed. On chrome, I can get as far as having the page pause when I hover over something but it just stops in somewhere in jquery and I still can't get to the call I want to inspect. Stepping through doesn't seem to help me find it.
Here is what I am trying to do and I hope someone will explain to to me how they do it like I'm an idiot, because I am.

I want to load my edit page into a modal dialog. I have modals working with BootstrapDialog and my edit page set up with an `<a href>`. I found an example that I think does this http://oscarotero.com/jquery/
and would like to examine the code that does this. I can't get to the js call that does it. I don't want to break immediately at the first event, I want to get to the event where I click the mouse and then see where in the js code the href is going into the modal dialog.  Currently I am just stuck in the jquery click event and can't find the mouseclick event for the modal that will lead to the href getting loaded. What are the specific steps you would take to do this?

Edit:    How do I inspect the site's code that looks like this at the point where the modal loads the href? (The code below is an example not from the site I am looking at but it's the area I want to examine on the site)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn.edit-attendee').click(function(e){
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(url);
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            message: $('<div></div>').load(url)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. How to step through JS? How to debug it? How to track AJAX requests? How to find a bug?

Comment: How do I see the JS source code where the `<a href>` is being loaded into the modal dialog window?

Answer (score 0):

Use debugger (when Firebug or other dev tools are open the code will stop and you can inspect it).

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn.edit-attendee').click(function(e){
        url = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(url); //replace this with -->
        debugger //edit
        BootstrapDialog.show({
        message: $('<div></div>').load(url)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I use the debugger but I can't get to the part of the code that shows the the Jquery being used. Now that I have tried for awhile, I think I might be unlucky that this particular site is making it hard on purpose. If you can do it I would appreciate to know how you did it.

Comment: You are using both Jquery library as Bootstrap library. Both core files can be downloaded from sites. When you add these core files to your webpage you should be able to debug the code. I did only a minute ago. I'm able to see all the code that is being executed. [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and [Jquery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js). I hope this helps.